# Задержка выполнения процедуры в Java

Tags: java

Подскажите как сделать задержку для выполнения определенной функции в коде Java. Код писал не я, я просто его модифицирую.

Чего я хочу добиться - при запуске Java программы открывается некое "окно" с кнопками и списком выбора, и пока кнопку не нажать, то выполнение программы далее не происходит. Список выбора подгружается из текстового файла.

Мне нужно чтобы программа как бы сама нажимала кнопку по прошествии например 10 мкс. Я пытался как то избавится от этого окна, но оно связано с дальнейшим выполнением программы и передает в основной код программы параметры выбора объектов из списка. Так что избавится от него я не могу, а вот как сделать виртуальное нажатие на кнопку не знаю, возможно и не нужен будет таймер или ещё что. Java программа предназначена для запуска на ПК (Только Windows).

!!!Видимо ответа я не дождусь, ладно, попробую как нибудь сам разобраться.

Comment: добавьте код пожалуйста чтобы мы могли представить всю картинку.

Comment: В сети есть множество примеров splash screen

Comment: Исходный код имеется?

Comment: Вот [ссылка](https://github.com/TigerHix/shimeji-ee) на исходник, а конкретно интересует файл src/com/group_finity/mascot/imagesetchooser/ImageSetChooser.java

Comment: @Ден Используйте что то вроде этого https://pastebin.com/BrEXTGKK Соответственно, метод надо сделать публичным. Так вы сделаете то что вам надо, не вникая в код.

Comment: @test123 Я наверное кажусь совсем идиотом, но я честно не понимаю что к чему в Java, как сказали на одном форуме, у меня "Delphi головного мозга". В какую часть вот [этого](https://pastebin.com/jjj8fRsW) кода нужно вставить тот, что вы дали? Я пробовал сделать по разному, но либо ничего просто не работает, либо вылазят ошибки.

Comment: @Ден Хорошо, скажите на какую конкретно кнопку вы нажимаете, и я покажу вам готовый код для этого метода run.

Comment: Кнопка Use Selected, т.к. код вроде как парсит содержимое папки, но вот эти Selected записаны в отдельный файл. Этот файл будет уже создавать лаунчер, который я пишу на Delphi.

Comment: Видимо ответа я не дождусь, ладно, попробую как нибудь сам разобраться.